# git svn windows linux whitespace problems

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I use git (with git-svn) on linux and a colleague uses svn on windows.

So many times, git reports whitespace issues. In fact it fails to commit a linear history because of these problems and creates merge conflicts.

What is the simplest way to configure svn/git and git-svn on windows and linux so that there are now whitespace issues?

Following is a reported merge conflict, in a linear history on master:

```
error: patch failed: frontend/templates/frontend/base.html:38
error: frontend/templates/frontend/base.html: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: frontend/templates/frontend/footer.html:1
error: frontend/templates/frontend/footer.html: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: frontend/templates/frontend/index.html:1
error: frontend/templates/frontend/index.html: patch does not apply
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:15: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:20: trailing whitespace.
          <a href="{% url frontend_index %}">
<stdin>:22: trailing whitespace.
          </a>
<stdin>:24: trailing whitespace.
        <span class="companyname">
<stdin>:25: trailing whitespace.
          <a href="{% url frontend_index %}">
warning: squelched 74 whitespace errors
warning: 79 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging frontend/templates/frontend/base.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in frontend/templates/frontend/base.html
Auto-merging frontend/templates/frontend/index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in frontend/templates/frontend/index.html
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 template changes

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

How do I solve the whitespace issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Fixing whitespace errors**

Add this to `.gitconfig`

```
[core]
  whitespace=nowarn
```

git rebase should now work.  (You can optionally add some of `fix,-indent-with-non-tab,trailing-space`  to that to have git fix all whitespaces at every commit. Whether that is a good idea depends on your project rules and team. )

**Fixing eol errors**

```
[core]
  autocrlf = true
```

in your `.gitconfig`.  This will force every text file to have windows line endings.  `svn` by default ignores line endings and if your text editors on windows are sane you can leave it that way.   Otherwise, add [this file](http://www.apache.org/dev/svn-eol-style.txt) to your svn config (optionally changing `native` to `CRLF`)  ensuring consistent CRLF line endings through out.

Set `autocrlf = input` and change `native` to  `LF` for consistently linux line endings throughout.