# Git rebase for a branch created days back

Tags: git, whitespace, git-rebase, git-merge

I need help in understanding git rebase for this situation. I checked out a branch created by some one 10 days back. I checked out using

```
git checkout -b <some name> origin/branchname
```

(I just used different name to identify it)

After checkout, if I do rebase by being in this checked out branch,

```
git rebase origin/master
```

It shows some errors like
1) Trailing whitespace - I read about this but even after trying this command that I found online, i still see the warnings.

```
 git config core.whitespace nowarn
```

2) Auto-merging 
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in...
these files are in master branch but the content is modified a little bit in the checkout branch. So how should I fix this? I don't have authority to change anything in master directly if that's the way to fix it. These files should have the content from this checkout branch so that the testing will work fine as it's related to that..please clarify me..

regards

Comment: for my first issue, i came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327917/git-svn-windows-linux-whitespace-problems, but can someone please explain the command I should run as I don't understand from the answer provided..thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys have pretty much answered the question about whitespaces but didn't touch the rebase part of the question. Here is what's happening when you rebase:

first your checking out to some branch, then you say:

```
git rebase master
```

This means that you would like to rebase the current HEAD (your topic branch) onto master.
Git is going back in history of your topic branch and in history of master branch and finds a commit that is a first common ancestor for both of them. This commit will be an old base for your topic branch. Then it takes all commits that happened since then in your branch and "reapplies" them in the order of appearance on top of the current master. Sometimes conflict can happen, then the rebase process stops and waits for your resolution. So you have have to manually resolve them by editing files and then marking them as resolved by `git add conflicted_file`
When this is done you will have to say `git rebase --continue`

Now you're NOT changing files in master branch by doing that - the changes are happening in your topic branch and conflicts resolution are recorded in your topic branch.

hope that helps.

Comment: yes this helps. so the changes that I am making on topic branch is same as what is in the master right? looks like this can be done only if one is confident that changes in Topic branch are not necessary...other wise why would someone resolve it matching it same content as the master?

Comment: nope, not really. Again changes that are recorded in topic branch are not affecting master branch at all. During the rebase operation master is becoming a new base for your topic branch commits, but the master pointer doesn't move. If you would like to promote the results of rebase to your master branch then you would need to checkout to master branch and do "git merge topic". This will result in fast forward merge and master pointer will be moved to point to the same commit as your topic branch does.

Comment: you can create a test repo and play with two branches by committing some different stuff and then try to rebase one on another. Before you do that run "gitk --all &". that will fire up the GUI for history browser. Then after each operation that you perform press F5 to update the GUI. That should show you how the process works and what are the results

Answer (score 1):

If this is anything like question "[git svn windows linux whitespace problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327917/git-svn-windows-linux-whitespace-problems)" that you mention, then the commands would be:

```
git config core.whitespace nowarn
git config core.autocrlf true
```

(to keep those settings locale to the current repo).
That would force all files to adopt one eol style, preventing a file on origin/master to have identical lines with a different eol that your own copy your are rebasing (which would explain the `CONFLICTS (add/add)` error messages).

But I remain dubious about `autocrlf true`, and prefer [managing eol style through `.gitattributes` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278).

Answer (score 0):

`cd` into the `.git` folder in your repo. You may not see this folder if you are using a files explorer that is not enabled to display hidden files or files with `.` or `_` in the front. Inside the `.git` folder you will have a file named `config`. Open it up in a text editor and you should be able to see a portion named `[core]`. Add the `whitespace = nowarn` in there. The other location where you can find `.gitconfig` is under your `home` directory if you are using a linux machine. If its on windows it depends on how you installed `git` (via cygwin or msysgit).

If msysgit see this question ([Where does git config --global get written to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to)) for the location of `.gitconfig` file. If its cygwin, then you can see its content by `cat ~/.gitconfig`.